# URL-rewriting with index in a "public" folder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I’m a newcomer in the development world. I desperately try to get the good URL. I checked the site for similar problems but I can’t find exactly what I need. Or I do it badly.

Here is the situation: I set up a project for a site whose the index.php file is in a folder named Public.

To be clearer, here is the URL I have now to reach the homepage of the built site:
**http:// Domain Name.com/ Folder / Name of the site/public**

My concern is about the folder Public: I don’t want it appears in the URL. 
Here is the URL I’d like to get:
**http:// Domain Name.com/ Folder / Name of the site**

In fact, I’d like this URL permits to get the index file placed in the folder "Public".

I can’t access the Apache configurations (shared host) so I have a .htaccess I placed in the project (i.e: **www/ Folder /Name of the site /.htaccess**). Here is its content:

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.html [NC,L]
```

I made something very simple for now because I tried lots of things without efficient result.

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure what you are trying to do, but if you want to remove the `/public/` path that appears in the URL, you need to remove it from all your links, second, turn off multiviews, it's not what you want, third, you need a rule to externally redirect the browser when a request is made for `/public/`, then you need to internally rewrite requests to point to public.

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On

# externally redirect, must match against %{THE_REQUEST}
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD|POST)\ /public/
RewriteRule ^/?public/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# internally rewrite it back, but we must first check that it's pointing to a valid resource:
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public%{REQUEST_URI} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public%{REQUEST_URI} -s
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Hi Jon. Thanks for your help. Yes I want to remove the /public/ path in the URL to access to the homepage. I tried your solution and I got a "403 Forbidden" message. Is my .htaccess at the good location (above the folder public)? Any other idea?

Comment: @Wook the htaccess file (or these rules at least) needs to be in your document root, the directory where public *is in*.

Comment: Given the structure of the site(www/Folder1/Folder-of-the-site) I thought Document_Root represented folder www. Anyway I put the htaccess in the folder of the site (the directory where public is in) and it doesn't work. I still have the "403".