# .htaccess: remove public from URL

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

**Question**

How can I remove */public/* from my URLs?

**Problem**

When I go to visit `/app/about` the URL changes to `/app/public/about` and `app/user/2` changes to `/app/user.php/?username=2`

**Setup**

### **/app/ .htaccess**

The `.htaccess` outside of the *public* folder contains:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /app/

# remove /public/ from URL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/public [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ public/$1
```

This works fine. When I visit `localhost:8888/app/` it loads up the `index.php` file inside the *public* folder.

### **/app/public/ .htaccess**

The `.htaccess` inside of the *public* folder contains:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# Add trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+[^/])$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . %1/ [L,R=301]

# API Pages
# ------------------------------------------------------------
RewriteRule ^user/([a-z0-9]+)/?$ user.php?username=$1 [L,NC]


# Generic Pages
# ------------------------------------------------------------
RewriteRule ^about/?$ about.php [L,NC]

# Error Pages
# ------------------------------------------------------------
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

**Related**:
[URL-rewriting with index in a "public" folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13165966/url-rewriting-with-index-in-a-public-folder)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `# Add trailing slash` rule appears to be problem. Can you try commenting it out for testing.

**/app/.htaccess**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /app/

## Adding a trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?[^/])[?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [L,R=301]

# remove /public/ from URL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/public/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ public/$1 [L]
```

Comment: 404. it's trying to redirect to `/app/public/app/`

Comment: ok, now its adding the `.php` back to `/app/about` and changing `/app/user/2` to `/app/user.php?username=2`.

Comment: hmm. still adds `.php` to about. and for `/app/user/2` changes to `/app/app/user.php/?username=/` For now, do you still have the version you did before I asked for the trailing slash?

Comment: ok I did. what it's doing now it removing the last character. `/app/about` becomes `/app/abou/` and `/app/user/2/` becomes `/app/user//`

Comment: ahhh, `/app/about/` now works. theres a 404 on `/app/user/2/` and now javascript and css files not being loaded. so close now

Comment: For css, js use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.

Comment: ahh works now. Thank you man, Can't be more grateful for your help. Much appreciated.