# Remove public folder from URL with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is it possible to 'remove' a folder from the URL so if somebody types `http://www.example.com/dummy/public/index` into their browser address bar, I can strip the 'public' folder, so the URL reads `http://www.example.com/dummy/index`

I essentially want to hide the 'public' folder so it never appears in the URL.

I have this htaccess at the root of my site which is www.example.com/dummy/

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*) public/$1 [L]
```

This is the htaccess inside my public folder which is located at www.example.com/dummy/public/

```
Options -MultiViews

# Activates URL rewriting (like myproject.com/controller/action/1/2/3)
RewriteEngine On

# Prevent people from looking directly into folders
Options -Indexes

# If the following conditions are true, then rewrite the URL:
# If the requested filename is not a directory,
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# and if the requested filename is not a regular file that exists,
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and if the requested filename is not a symbolic link,
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
# then rewrite the URL in the following way:
# Take the whole request filename and provide it as the value of a
# "url" query parameter to index.php. Append any query string from
# the original URL as further query parameters (QSA), and stop
# processing this .htaccess file (L).
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I tried changing the last RewriteRule to `RewriteRule ^(.+)public/(.*)$ index.php?url=$1$2 [QSA,L]` but when I type `www.example.com/dummy/public/index` the page loads but the browser address bar still shows 'public' in the path.

Is it possible to do what I'm attempting?

I've seen a few SO answers that claim to accomplish this such as [.htaccess: remove public from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19708714/htaccess-remove-public-from-url) and [URL-rewriting with index in a "public" folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13165966/url-rewriting-with-index-in-a-public-folder), but none of them work for me.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to remove `public/` from your URLs then rule should be placed inside `/public/.htaccess` since all the requests with URI starting with `/dummy/public/` will be managed by rules inside `/public/.htaccess`.

Change your `/public/.htaccess` with this:

```
# Prevent people from looking directly into folders
Options -Indexes -MultiViews

# Activates URL rewriting (like myproject.com/controller/action/1/2/3)
RewriteEngine On

# remove public/ from URLs using a redirect rule
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+/)?public/(\S*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2? [R=301,L,NE]

# If the following conditions are true, then rewrite the URL:
# If the requested filename is not a directory,
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# and if the requested filename is not a regular file that exists,
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and if the requested filename is not a symbolic link,
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
# then rewrite the URL in the following way:
# Take the whole request filename and provide it as the value of a
# "url" query parameter to index.php. Append any query string from
# the original URL as further query parameters (QSA), and stop
# processing this .htaccess file (L).
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks anubhava. I'll test this solution as soon as I can and report back whether it works for me or not

Answer (score 0):

Fear not! For the answer is yes. Use the following rule in your `.htaccess` to remove the `/public/` folder from your URLs:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/public /$1 [R=301,L]
```

This will leave you with the desired URL of `http://www.example.com/dummy/index` and it achieves this using a `301` permanent redirection. For testing purposes I suggest you change this to `302` as this will make it temporary, once happy, change it back.

Make sure you clear your cache **before** testing this.

Comment: Thanks Lag. I've replaced RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L] with RewriteRule ^(.*)/public /$1 [R=301,L] but when I go to www.example.com/dummy/public/ the URL doesn't change - it still shows the 'public' bit at the end. I cleared my cache and tried a different browser just in case

Comment: Have you tried commenting out those conditions? I'm seeing no real need for their use in your .htaccess

Comment: Which conditions are you talking about commenting out Lag? The project I'm using as a base is https://github.com/panique/huge which is also where the 2 htaccess files come from

Comment: You have three `RewriteCond` which are specifically for the Rewrite Rule `RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]`. They're not needed for my Rewrite above. However, I'm also thinking if you've put the code in the root, then the `.htaccess` in `/public/` will overwrite it. So it would need to go into that .htaccess instead.